# CSS hover and background color

Tags: css

smarter people than me!

I've been racking my brain for awhile with some css for [this wordpress website](http://everythreeweekly.com/) On the navigation menu (Campus, National, World,...) I'm trying to do some custom css where when you hover your mouse over the menu items and they change color. Right now they only turn black except for the Campus menu item which changes to what I want for a moment then changes to black.

My attempt was to try this short css in the stylesheet, but it didn't work. I suspect I might have to adjust the upper-nested classes.

```
.menu-item-28 a:hover{
      background:#1f61c4;
}
```

This is probably an easy question but my css-fu is pretty bad. Any help help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question incomplete and thus, impossible to answer

Comment: use `background-color:#1f61c4;` . the background shorthand often doesn't work well on non-mainstream browsers /setups.

Comment: I think [these lines](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EuQ43.png) is the problem

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes that only shows the calculated css (which correctly shows it's not applying the colour) but it does not tell why the colour is not applied

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selector to

```
#menu-main-navigation li a:hover{
      background-color:#1f61c4;
}
```

This will target any anchor (`a`) inside your main navigation (instead of only the one found under `.menu-item-28` - ie. campus)

Answer (score 0):

There is this CSS rule in the code

```
#nav nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #222222;
    border-color: #222222;
    color: #fff;
}
```

which causes the black background on hover. You probably can't change that, I suppose. But if you put another rule somewhere "later" (= below it) in the code, you can overwrite it with your own background color:

```
#nav nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #1f61c4;
}
```